# Syntax issues grabing a value from my query

Tags: c#, .net, database, data-binding

Im trying to grab a value from my query. Im gettign a sintax error. 
It contains a picture name mypic.jpg. Then i want to display that on my page.

This is what im doing how do i do this correctly.

display.aspx

```
<asp:Image ID="Img1" ImageUrl="pathToPicture" runat="server" />
```

display.aspx.cs

```
Picture DLtestPicture = new Picture();
DataTable DTTestPicture = DLtestPicture.GetRandomPicture();
String pathToPicture = DTTestPicture.Rows(0).Item("PicLoc").ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use indexers instead:

```
String pathToPicture = DTTestPicture.Rows[0]["PicLoc"].ToString();
```

Alternatively - and preferrably, IMO - change `GetRandomPicture` to return a strongly-typed value rather than a `DataTable`. It could *at least* just return a single `DataRow` explicitly, rather than returning a table.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (DTTestPicture.Rows.Count >= 0) 
{
  string pathToPicture= Convert.ToString(DTTestPicture.Rows[0]["PicLoc"]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I got it worked out now. Much apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
DTTestPicture.Rows(0).Item("PicLoc")
```

It is not a C# syntax. use `[]` on the place of `()` for `containers`/ Index based object.

Correct Syntax:

```
DTTestPicture.Rows[0].Item["PicLoc"]
```

On the place of `toString()` use `Convert.ToString()` for to avoid null value exception.

```
Convert.ToString(DTTestPicture.Rows[0].Item["PicLoc"]);
```